# How to change number of spaces depending on digits in integer?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to print out the values in an array with line numbers at the start of each line. I'd like to change the spacing to make sure the values line up vertically regardless of the size of the array.

```
@lines.each_with_index {|l,i|
  newtext = l[:text]
  space = ' ' * @lines.size.to_s.size
  cur_space = i.to_s.size
  (1..cur_space).each { space.chop! }

  puts "\##{i}#{space} #{newtext}"
}
```

Output

```
#0  blah
#1  blah
#2  blah
#3  blah
#4  blah
#5  blah
#6  blah
#7  blah
#8  blah
#9  blah
#10 blah
#11 blah
#12 blah
#13 blah
```

This works, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for[`String#ljust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-ljust):

```
index_size = @lines.size.pred.to_s.size

@lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  puts "##{index.to_s.ljust(index_size)} #{line[:text]}"
end
```

Comment: Seems like the best answer. If your using ruby2.4 or higher I would use `@lines.size.pred.digits.count`

Answer (score 2):

you can use tabs:

```
2.2.4 :001 > class Tabs
2.2.4 :002?>   def self.do_it
2.2.4 :003?>     (1..13).each do |number|
2.2.4 :004 >         puts "##{number}\tblah"
2.2.4 :005?>       end
2.2.4 :006?>     end
2.2.4 :007?>   end
=> :do_it
2.2.4 :008 > Tabs.do_it
#1  blah
#2  blah
#3  blah
#4  blah
#5  blah
#6  blah
#7  blah
#8  blah
#9  blah
#10 blah
#11 blah
#12 blah
#13 blah
```

Comment: Clever. It won't work for huge ids, but it's probably not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) with `"%-3d"` :

- `-` : Left-justify the result of this conversion.
- `d` : Convert argument as a decimal number.

---

```
n       = 14
width   = (n-1).to_s.size
pattern = "#%-#{width}d %s"

n.times do |i|
  puts format(pattern, i, 'blah')
end
```

It outputs :

```
#0  blah
#1  blah
#2  blah
#3  blah
#4  blah
#5  blah
#6  blah
#7  blah
#8  blah
#9  blah
#10 blah
#11 blah
#12 blah
#13 blah
```